# Нейросети и машинное обучение - это два разных понятия?

Tags: нейронные-сети, машинное-обучение

Нейросети и машинное обучение - это два разных понятия? Ведь машинное обучение производится на заранее  подготовленных данных, а для нейросети они вроде бы не нужны - я встпечал такое определение: Нейросеть - это алгоритм, который спсобен сам уточнять входной параметр.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Вы задали слишком философский вопрос. Каждый на него ответит по-своему. Моём мнение Вы можете узнать ниже.

Сейчас нейросети (НС) воспринимаются многими как панацея. Приведу пример. Если Вы спросите: "Как можно решить какую-либо задачу, поставленную нечётко?" Например, как узнать, в какой момент произойдёт отток клиентов в банке, либо же, в какой момент Петечкин Василий Петрович перестанет платить кредит. Скорее всего Вас отошлют к нейросетям и скажут: а возьмите-ка ваши данные подайте на вход нейронной сети и будет Вам счастье. Этот подход имеет место быть и он неплох, особенно, когда следует получить быстрый результат в условиях ограниченного времени. Скорее всего Вы получите приемлемое качество при наличии небольшой сноровки работы с НС.

Но вот на вопрос, что можно использовать помимо НС, скорее всего Вы получите в ответ задумчивое молчание. После чего, вероятно, человек выпалит фразу, в которой будет фигурировать слово "регрессия" или "метод главных компонент". Да, всё это прекрасные методы, но часто люди ими и ограничиваются.

Многие модели эквивалетны друг другу. Так, регрессию можно представить нейросетью, а нейросеть регрессией. И ничего здесь странного нет. Также и с другими методами.

Что касается панацеи. То сейчас забывают о многих чудесных вещах. Например, о дифференциальных уравнениях, которые могут очень неплохо описывать разного класса задачи. О теории групп, посредствам которой можно очень здорово упрощать всеми любимые НС и повышать качество так называемого обучения, которое явлется решением оптимизационной задачи.Что касается НС, то всё это сводит к введению целевой функции, которую следует оптимизировать.

Отвечая на Ваш вопрос про машинное обучение и НС. Машинное обучение -- это набор математических методов прикладной математики, которые, в большинстве  своём проходят в курсах высшей школы (численные методы, методы оптимизации, статистика, анализ, дискретная математика и другие). НС -- есть метод прикладной математики, который направлен на решение определённого класса задач. Следовательно, НС -- это семейство алгоритмов, являющихся частью машинного обучения, которые, как правило, можно отнести к численным методам и методам оптимизации.

Comment: Возможно, НС воспринимаются как панацея из-за того, что само название НС - неадекватно. Например, перцептрон это просто набор матриц и нелинейная функция. При чем тут нейроны?

Comment: @AlexanderZonov некоторые структуры, которые используются в нейронах подчерптуны из биологии. Но, если мы сравниваем модельный нейрон ИНС с реальным биологическим нейроном, то сходства здесь довольно мало.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно добавить что после обучения с примерами,нейросеть может предлагать правильный или близкий к правильному ответу,получая данные которые не были в исходном обучающем наборе-она теперь умеет обобщать.

Answer (score 0):

А с нейронными сетями еще не вполне понятна грань между классическим математическим моделированием и машинным обучением. В классическом моделировании изучалось какое-то физическое явление, его природа, выводились формулы, данные формализовывались, оставшиеся параметры вычислялись. У нас было много знаний о мире и мало данных. Так было в физике, химии, биологии. Но чем в менее формализованные области мы уходим — в психологию, социологию, экономику, в сложные технические системы, — тем сложнее создать для них системы уравнений. А если это и получается сделать, то они выходят настолько сложными, что модель просто разваливается. Мы перестали управлять этой сложностью.

А в машинном обучении функции как бы натягиваются, прилаживаются к существующим данным, о которых мы ничего не знаем и которые определяем как универсальное семейство, способное приблизить любую функцию. Это могут делать нейронные сети, но не обязательно только они. Появляются миллионы способов аппроксимации функций, и мы уже понимаем, какие методы для чего лучше работают.

[Источник](https://postnauka.ru/faq/86374)

Answer (score -1):

Машинное обучение — это просто категория в computer science, оно делается с помощью нейросетей, взятых из биологических моделей.

Comment: Что-то так себе ответ...